# Mapreduce and hive difference

Tags: hive, mapreduce

I want to know the difference between hive and map reduce
And if there any comparision between them.
Does hive also show some part of map reduce

Answer (score 0):

Hive and MapReduce have completely different purpose, they are like oranges and apples.

[MapReduce](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#Purpose) is a software framework for writing applications which process big amounts of data on large clusters in parallel.

[Hive](https://hive.apache.org/) is a database for processing large datasets residing in the distributed file system using SQL. Hive on Tez and Hive on MapReduce translates SQL queries into series of mapReduce jobs (Tez execution engine uses DAGs).

MapReduce is general purpose purpose framework (a set of libraries and tools), you can use it to write your own MapReduce application in Java, Python, Scala, R.

And Hive is SQL database, it has reach SQL and data warehousing features and cost-based optimizer for building optimal query plan.